# writing an Eigen_decomposition with numpy and tensorflow

Tags: arrays, numpy, tensorflow, svd

I have written  the same code in numpy and tensoflow 1.14

Numpy version:

```
Ux, _, _ =randomized_svd(Xn, n_components=n)


# Project X and Y onto  Principal components
Yproj=np.matmul((Ux.T), Yn)
Xproj=np.matmul((Ux.T), Xn)


Uyx, _, Vyx =randomized_svd(np.matmul(Yproj, Xproj.T), n_components=n)
K_reg= np.matmul(Uyx,Vyx.T)

## Eigen_decomposition


[m, n] = K_reg.shape
[Eigval_Proc, Eigvec_Proc] = np.linalg.eig(K_reg)
```

tensorflow 1.14:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.linalg import inv eig


_, Ux , _ =tf.linalg.svd(Xn, full_matrices=False, compute_uv=True)

# # Project X and Y onto  Principal components
Yproj=tf.matmul(tf.transpose(Ux), Yn)
Xproj=tf.matmul(tf.transpose(Ux), Xn)


_, Uyx, Vyx =tf.linalg.svd(tf.matmul(Yproj, tf.transpose(Xproj)),full_matrices=False, compute_uv=True)

K_reg= tf.matmul(Uyx,tf.transpose(Vyx))

[Eigval_Proc, Eigvec_Proc] = np.linalg.eig(K_reg)
```

For numpy, it works properly, but I am struggling with the tensorflow version: the error comes in the last line

```
[Eigval_Proc, Eigvec_Proc] = np.linalg.eig(K_reg)
```

I hope that you can help me. I am not sure how to do the eigedecomposition with tensorflow

Comment: and what's the error?... arent you feeding a tensor to a numpy function?

Comment: This is the error, that I am feeding a tensor to a numpy function, I have tried to use:  ```Eigval_Proc, Eigvec_Proc = tf.linalg.eig(K_reg)``` but it does not work as "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.linalg' has no attribute 'eig'
"

Comment: Update your tensorflow version

Comment: probably looking for this https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/eigvalsh